# Java Eclipse IStructuredSelection in different ViewParts returns null

Tags: java, eclipse, view, selection

at first I checked the other topics about the `IStructuredSelection` here on StackOverflow but they doesn´t solve my problem.

So I have 2 Views. In both Views I have a `TreeViewer` and implemented `getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);`

In the MainView everything is working correctly, when I click on a `TreeNode` (**NOTE:** These `TreeNode`'s are from a custom class, lets say `myTreeNode`) the `PropertiesView` gets updated and my popup `menu` with different handlers calls the correct function.

One of these functions create a new `TreeItem` in the other `View`, which should display some values in different columns. These values get updated every second. This part is also working correctly.

But now the problem occur. When I click on one of the `TreeItem`'s, the PropertiesView does not get updated and the popup menu handler is also not working correctly. The `IStructuredSelection strucSelection = (IStructuredSelection) selection;` always returns `null`.

Here is my `getAdapter` method from my adapter for the `PropertiesView`:

```
@Override
public Object getAdapter(Object adaptableObject, Class adapterType)
{
    if(adapterType == IPropertySource.class && adaptableObject instanceof UATreeNode)
        return new UATreeNodeAdapter((UATreeNode) adaptableObject);
    else if(adapterType == IPropertySource.class && adaptableObject instanceof TreeItem)
    {
        MainView.printOnOPCUAConsole(OPCUAConsoleMessageTypeEnum.NULL, "Instanceof TreeItem");
        return new TreeItemAdapter((TreeItem) adaptableObject);
    }
    else if(adapterType == IPropertySheetPage.class)
    {
        if(propertyPage == null)
            propertyPage = new PropertySheetPage();
        return propertyPage;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here is my `Handler`, which should be called, when the `menu` in the second view is opend and a command is executed:

```
@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException
{
    ISelection selection = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getSelectionService().getSelection();
    if(selection instanceof IStructuredSelection)
    {
        IStructuredSelection strucSelection = (IStructuredSelection) selection;

        if(strucSelection.getFirstElement() != null)
        {
            TreeItem treeItem = (TreeItem) strucSelection.getFirstElement();
            UaSubscription uaSubscription = (UaSubscription) treeItem.getData("uaSubscription");

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In both cases, the selection is null but I can see that something is selected, because otherwise I think the `popup menu` would not be displayed.

So my question now, does anybody know how to get the selection from my second `View` ? And what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That suggests that there is something wrong with your `setSelectionProvider` call for the second view or maybe something else is the active part.

Comment: In the second view I also pass the treeViewer to the `setSelectionProvider`.
I recognized, when the second view gets focus, that the first element of the viewer is always "auto-selected" and my `SelectionChangedListener` gets fired. But here I have the same problem, that the `event.getSelection();` returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem with implementing my own elements and provide them via `ContentProvider` to the `TreeViewer`.
Then I added a new adaptableType(the new created class) for the `adapter-extension` in the plugin.xml and added the new `Class` to the `adapter-factory`.